# Extract all dataframes from a list which contains certain columns

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list like:

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26)
Hight <- c(13, 41, 32, 58, 26)
Weight <- c(11,43,23,43,123)

df1 <- data.frame(Name, Age, Hight, Weight)
df2 <- data.frame(Name, Age, Hight)
df3<- data.frame(Name, Age, Weight)

l <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

I want now to extract all dataframes (or the name of the dataframes), which contain the Hight andWeight columns.

The expected output in this case would `list(df1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
l <- list(df1, df2, df3)

l[sapply(l , \(x) all(c('Weight', 'Hight') %in% colnames(x)))]
```

- output

```
[[1]]
   Name Age Hight Weight
1   Jon  23    13     11
2  Bill  41    41     43
3 Maria  32    32     23
4   Ben  58    58     43
5  Tina  26    26    123
```

Comment: You can use `sapply` to skip the `unlist` step

Comment: Or can try `Filter(\(x) all(c("Hight", "Weight") %in% names(x)), l)`

Comment: @Ben this could be a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Purrr comes with `keep()` / `discard()`:

```r
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

purrr::keep(dfs, ~ all(c("Hight", "Weight") %in% colnames(.x)))
#> [[1]]
#>    Name Age Hight Weight
#> 1   Jon  23    13     11
#> 2  Bill  41    41     43
#> 3 Maria  32    32     23
#> 4   Ben  58    58     43
#> 5  Tina  26    26    123
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using a `for` loop:

```
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)

n <- length(dfs)
index <- NULL # index of dataframes to be used
for (i in 1:n){
  if ("Hight" %in% names(dfs[[i]]) & "Weight" %in%  names(dfs[[i]]))
    index <- c(index, i)
}

dfs[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)
have_all_columns <- purrr:::map_lgl(df_list, ~all(c( "Hight", "Weight") %in% names(.x)))
df_list[have_all_columns]
```